# Using THREE.js json loader with webpack

Tags: webpack, three.js

I'm having a hard time making the THREE json loader work with webpack.

Should I write:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();    
jsonLoader.load("./foobar.json", function(g, m) { ... });
```

or should I require the json:

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();    
jsonLoader.load(require("./foobar.json"), function(g, m) { ... });
```

If dont require the json, I get a 404 error, since the file is simply not emitted outside the src folder.

If require it, I get a weird error coming from Three.js (so I guess I'm not supposed to require it, but I might be wrong)

Comment: This really depends on how your webpack is configured. But generally you do need to require it so webpack can figure out what to do with it. Without a require, you should put it in some `static/foobar.json` path. Also, what is the "weird" error, what does it say?

Comment: There is a `jsonLoader.parse( jsonObject, ... )` method, which is probably what you want if the JSON is bundled by webpack. [Docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/JSONLoader.parse).